# Avoid creation of .k5login file in a SFTP Chroot configuration

Tags: ssh, sftp, active-directory

I've successfully set up an sftp with authentication on Active Directory. All users in a particular AD group are managed by SSH's sftp subsystem and chrooted into a common home directory, let's say /upload.

This works fine except that everytime a user logs in, a file named **.k5login** is created and remains there. I could delete the file, but whenever a user logs in, the file is created again.

I've used pbis-open to connect the workstation to the domain, but I think my issue is not related to this particular package.

From what I saw, this file is required by the kerberos authentication framework, but how **can I avoid this**? Can I modify the creation path of this file, let's say in /tmp?